# Can LibreOffice Writer automatically recognise the spell-check language while writing?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Can LO Writer automatically detect the language in which the current line of text is being composed and based on this automatically change the spell-check language accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each document has a default language, and other languages can be specified for a particular paragraph or character style.

Also if one language uses a Western font and the other language uses an Asian or CTL font, then LibreOffice can automatically recognize which language is which.

See https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Selecting_the_Document_Language for details.